# Are there any tutorials available for node reference url

Tags: 7, nodes

Does anyone have a tutorial link to show me how to use node references with custom content types, ie. QUESTIONS and ANSWERS, in D7?

Comment: Please title your question more appropriately, currently, when seeing it in the overview, it's _really_ unhelpful.

Comment: say this before you subtract points, i am new, sheesh

Comment: Try reading through [ask]

Comment: Rather than trying node reference, have you tried the [Answers](http://drupal.org/project/answers) module?

Comment: I actually FINALLY got the answers module to work.  It was giving me issues so it's not perfect but it functions now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will find you masses of tutorials.

e.g.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CHC8I9xZIg

Above is the [first hit in the video search](https://www.google.de/search?q=drupal+node+reference+url+tutorial#q=drupal+node+reference+url+tutorial&hl=de&prmd=imvnsfd&source=lnms&tbm=vid&ei=XJnPT9OeBYnPtAarzqWVCw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=4&ved=0CDcQ_AUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=faea6f5a7f8c126b&biw=1585&bih=721). But there is much more.